# Modal dialog options

Tags: javascript

I am opening a window as a modal.
    window.showModalDialog("http://www.google.com","","dialogWidth:500px;dialogHeight:500px")

as I set height, what are other options available?
Like option buttons, menus etc. where I can find tutorials?

**EDIT**

*It works in Mozilla firefox, but people are saying it doesn't!*

My code is

Please somebody Edit my sample code for display purpose

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function abc() {
        window.showModalDialog("3.htm", "", "dialogWidth:500px;dialogHeight:500px");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="check" name="check" onclick="abc()" value="open"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**Second EDIT**

code for page 3.htm

```
     <html>
<head>
<script>
function abc(){
close()
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="check" name="check" onclick="abc()" value="close"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Check out both code on fire fox! and tell me.

**Third EDIT**

Ok It's not working in corme and opera

Comment: Which modal window code are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that showModalDialog is IE specific and won't necessarily work with other browsers. If you want cross browser modal dialogs you need to use a div to hide the rest of the page and overlay your dialog on top. It is easier to use an existing javascript library that already takes care of this.

Comment: This is no longer true as of Firefox 3.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to use popups in web apps. Use floating divs instead which looks like a modal dialog but are better than the popups.

Answer (score 0):

[JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) has a decent popup/modal dialog API and I've worked with the [Boxy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/) plugin which is very easy to implement.

They're cross browser and simple to use.

Comment: Yes I've seen that, but they fails to open new page on the same boxy window.

Answer (score 0):

To load a page using boxy use:

```
var boxyPopup;
Boxy.load("aPage.html",
            {title: "Title",
            modal: true,
            fixed: false,
            afterShow: function(){
                boxyPopup = this;}});
```

I'm not sure what you mean by it not opening a new page on same boxy window but using the above you have the boxyPopup var as a reference to the open boxy object and can access/change contents using that.